# How to install maven-site-plugin 3.0 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: maven, plugins

I installed maven 3.0.4 by using `apt-get install maven`, but how to install the `maven-site-plugin 3.0` , the synaptic package manager shows there are only `libmaven-site-plugin-java 2.1-2` and `libjavacc-maven-site-plugin-java 2.6-2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never install the maven-site-plugin via operating system (or in ubuntu) you will using it via your pom by defining it like this:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          ...
   ...
```

See also the [documentation about the maven-site-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html).

Comment: thanks, I'm new to maven, and I'm going to read the configuration.

Comment: Furthermore i recommend to read the following information: http://sonatype.com/Support/Books/